# Two GET methods with different number of query parameters : REST

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I have an Rest endpoint class as below :

```
@Path("/sports")
public interface SportsEndpoint {

    @GET
    List<Player> getPlayersOfSports(@QueryParam("sportId") String sportId, @QueryParam("sportName") String sportName);


    @GET
    List<Player> getPlayersOfSports(@QueryParam("sportId") String sportId, @QueryParam("sportName") String sportName, @QueryParam("country") String country);

}
```

As you can see, I have two `GET` methods which has almost the same signature except the second method takes an additional `QueryParam`.

I try to access these endpoints using the urls:

`http://localhost:8080/rest/api/sports?sportId=100&sportName=badminton`
`http://localhost:8080/rest/api/sports?sportId=100&sportName=badminton&country=japan`

Both these urls are resolving to use the first method signature. Ideally, I was expecting that for the first url, the first method signature would be called and for the second url the second method(the one with 3 query parameters) would have been called.
But looks like in both cases the first method is getting called.

I know that Rest resources are uniquely identified by the path and not the query parameters. But is it also true that even though the number of query parameters are different, the rest endpoint will not be uniquely identified ?
Can someone point me to some specifications/articles/documentation where I can understand polymorphism when it comes to designing rest api endpoints ?

FYI: I am using RestEasy.

Comment: In short, Jax-Rs uses the path information to resolve the method invoked. If multiple methods may match the first one ist used. What you can do is remove the first method as it is already covered by the second one and check inside if the last parameter is null or not. As query parameters are considered optional parameters if they are not available your framework should inject a null value (or default value if you specified one) instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QueryParams are the optional params as

> you correctly stated  I know that Rest resources are uniquely
> identified by the path and not the query params

and to answer your question ,

> yes even though the number of query parameters are different, the rest
> endpoint will not be uniquely identified ? as it is identified by the
> path not the query params.

If you want that your methods should be called based on the no of inputs in your `querystring`
it is better to create a single method, which takes all the `queryparam` according to your requirement and based on the no of inputs provided, you call each methods separately.

So in your case, it can be rewritten as below :-

```java
@Path("/sports")
public class SportsEndpoint {
        
    @GET
    List<Player> getPlayers(@QueryParam("sportId") String sportId, 
                            @QueryParam("sportName") String sportName,
                            @QueryParam("country") String country){
        if(sportId != null && sportName != null) {
            getPlayersOfSports(sportId,sportName);
        } else if (sportId != null && sportName != null && country != null) {
            getPlayersOfSports(sportId,sportName,country);
        }
    }
}
```

And

> then you define the method overloading in your business logic, which
> will have 2 overloaded methods, which varies based on no of arguments.
> This way you can achieve polymorphism.

Comment: Upvoting your answer and marking it as the correct answer.

Comment: @RITZXAVI Thanks.

Comment: This totally ignores lifecycle of software and the fact that you can't always refactor old client while introducing new query parameters

Answer (score 6):

Java rest APIs are implementation of Jax-Rs as far as i know, so you can read [Jax-Rs specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr339/index.html) ,

Jax-Rs maps Path to Resource method. Resource methods must have a unique path. Query params are not considered part of the path. Resource methods are methods of a resource class annotated with a request method designator. It is not determined by the specs what should happen when two methods share the same designator and path, but most implementation will use only one of them and will not report error.

(Conforms with the [URL specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-1.1.3). )

This means that you cannot use overloading.

Inheritance is allowed. From the Jax-Rs spec:

> JAX-RS annotations MAY be used on the methods and method parameters of a super-class or an implemented interface. Such annotations are inherited by a corresponding sub-class or implementation class method provided that method and its parameters do not have any JAX-RS annotations of its own. Annotations on a super-class take precedence over those on an implemented interface. If a subclass or implementation method has any JAX-RS annotations then all of the annotations on the super class or interface method are ignored. E.g.:

Comment: This does not answer my question. I know how to use Query params. I am not asking that. I want to know how polymorphism works when it comes to designing rest endpoint so that could understand why my second method never gets called even though I pass 3 query parameters.

Comment: Upvoting your answer.