# How to handle format query parameter in JAXRS-2?

Tags: java, api, rest, jax-rs

I want to expose REST API.
I want to know what format to return the resource using `format` Query parameter?
Based on it I want to choose appropriate controller.

example:
`GET /resources/sub-resources?format={valid_formats}&queryParam1={some-selector}........`

I want something that can do this

```java
@Path("resources/sub-resources")
public interface SubResource {
    @GET
    Response getSubResourceFormatBase64(@QueryParam("queryParam1") queryParam1);

    @GET
    Response getSubResourceFormatPlainString(@QueryParam("queryParam1") queryParam1);
}
```

Instead of this

```java
@Path("resources/sub-resources")
public interface SubResource {
    @GET
    Response getSubResource(@QueryParam("format") format, @QueryParam("queryParam1") queryParam1);
}
```

And select internally how to return for the format type.
How do I achieve this?

**Note**: format has to be a query paramter

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559180/two-get-methods-with-different-number-of-query-parameters-rest this might help you.

Comment: In the link, they have concluded that only path params are the ones that map to unique operations. But thanks anyhow.

Comment: In case format has to be a query param, I see no way than you checking that value and act based on it on a single method. You would be able to use different methods in case you use mime types, for example each method can be annotated as @Consumes("plain/text) or @Consumes("application/json")

Answer (score 0):

Why not something like this:

```
@Path("resources/sub-resources")
public interface SubResource {
    @GET
    @Path("/base64")
    Response getSubResourceFormatBase64(@QueryParam("queryParam1") queryParam1);

    @GET
    @Path("/plainString")
    Response getSubResourceFormatPlainString(@QueryParam("queryParam1") queryParam1);
}
```

so that the format would be kind a path variable or so?

Comment: Unfortunately, we were looking to use `format` as query param instead of path param